# multiprocess.Pool hangs

Tags: subprocess, pool

I'm using `multiprocess.Pool` to run several `git clone` process, but when there is a git repo much larger than others, the `git clone` process hangs.

The Pool I used as follows

```py
def ProcessHelper(runfunc,incl_infos,project_root,skip_dirs):
    p = Pool(processNum)
    multi_res = [p.apply_async(runfunc, args=(incl_info,project_root,skip_dirs,)) for incl_info in incl_infos]
    p.close()
    p.join()
    resMesList = []
    for res in multi_res:
        resMes = str(res.get())
        if (resMes.find("Failed") != -1):
            resMesList.append(resMes)
```

Then thread function use to check whether it's a git repo and clone the data if it is.

```py
def runfunc(incl_info,project_root,skip_dirs):
    if incl_info == 0:
        git_url = project_root["git_url"]
        dir_path = project_root["dir_path"]
        GitCloneInShell(git_url,dir_path)

def GitCloneInShell(git_url,dir_path):
        cmd = ("git clone %s %s " % (git_url, dir_path))
        LogInfo("git clone cmd : %s" % cmd)
        status = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
        return status
```

It usually works well. But when deal with a large repo with some other smaller repos, it will hangs on the large repo.
[image]

Can anyone give me some suggestions please ? Thanks a lot.